# trabajar con github en 2 pc diferentes

Tags: git, vscode, github

he estado desarrollando un trabajo y he estado utilizando git y github, la cosa es que la laptop se averió y quiero trabajar desde otro pc , pero ahora me pide credenciales. ingrese las mismas credenciales que tenia en el otro pc, pero aun así me  las pide en el otro no me las pedía.
que debo hacer para poder trabajar desde cualquiera de los 2 , todo el proyecto lo tengo en un disco externo a si que eso no es problema gracias

Comment: que tipo de credenciales te esta reclamando? cada pc puede tener sus propias credenciales, o usar todos las mismas si usas por ejemplo una clave publica/privada... no esta mal que pida credenciales.. tal vez la otra  pc no las pedia porque le pusiste que recordara tu clave?

Comment: Estas utilizando la terminal de git para iniciar sesión?, así mismo los comandos $ git `config --global user.name "John Doe"` y `$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com` , también puedes verificar el archivo .gitconfig en tu equipo windows

Answer (score 0):

Tu clave anterior funcionaba porque github permitía el acceso con contraseña hasta hace poco tiempo.

Ahora necesitas un Personal Access Token. [Aquí](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) te dice como crear uno.

Comment: al generar este token podre acceder y realizar push, pull u clonar desde cualquier pc?

Comment: Si, de hecho te da la opcion para que definas granularmente las operaciones que necesitas.